# jacoco - Generate Report on external maven module with tests into an application

Tags: jacoco-maven-plugin

**USE CASE**

I have developed a spring-shell based maven module `apim-library`.

And then I developed an application `apim-cli` which has `apim-library` as a dependency and only the Application class with main.

I am writing Unit Tests using JUnit5, Mockito, etc in the application `src/test/java/` but I want tests the classes into `apim-library`.

**WHAT AM I USING**

1. VSCode
2. Java 17
3. Spring Boot 3.1.3
4. Spring Shell 3.1.3
5. Jacoco 0.8.10
6. Maven 3.9.4

**WHAT HAPPENS**

The library and the application are in the same workspace.
I ran `mvn clean install` in the library project and it was successfully compiled and installed.
I set up the application's pom.xml to generate a report with jacoco:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>initialize</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>com/apim/**</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run the `mvn clean test` and `mvn jacoco:report` commands, only the Application class report is generated.

How should I do to have a Jacoco report with the coverage of the external maven module classes?

Comment: does specifying `<inclNoLocationClasses>true</inclNoLocationClasses>` in plugin configuration help?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work